# display a label after the Button is clicked in Java swing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I want to display a label, when a button is clicked. I am using Eclipse Juno. I have the label added and  setting the visible part...

```
wLabel = new JLabel("YOu and Me");
    wLabel .setVisible(false);
    wLabel .setBounds(80, 35, 100, 25);
    wLabel .setFont(new Font("Meiryo", Font.PLAIN, 9));
    wLabel .setForeground(new Color(255, 102, 21));
    add(wLabel);
```

the button

```
wButton = new JButton("W");
    wButton .setActionCommand("myButton");
    wButton .addActionListener(this);
    wButton .setFont(new Font("Meiryo UI", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    wButton .setBounds(10, 33, 70, 35);
    wButton .setBackground(new Color(102, 51, 20));
    add(wButton);
```

and here is the actionPerformed. I already implemented ActionListener

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("myButton")) {
        wLabel.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: wButton = new JButton("W");
  wButton.setActionCommand("myButton");
  wButton.setFont(new Font("Meiryo UI", Font.PLAIN, 11));
  wButton.setBounds(10, 32, 80, 30);
  wButton.setBackground(new Color(102, 51, 0));
  add(wButton);
  wButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("myButton")) {
     wLabel.setVisible(true);
   }
  }});

Comment: It is still not working if I do it like this

Comment: try to put e.g. System.out.println() to check if method is called. and if it won't work, try to remove `if(..)` statement

Comment: Whenever there's an issue in the form of "my component isn't showing and I don't know why", you MUST show us everything you've done to (1) create the component (2) add the component to a panel, and (3) add the panel to a top-level container. You haven't done that so far. For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. Many times, just creating the example will reveal the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially you can set the visibility to false of your label and after clicking the button set the visibility like `label.setVisible(true)`

for e.g. like this, note i am using lamba syntax for java 8

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BtnDisabled {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("You and Me");
        label.setVisible(false);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);

        JButton btn = new JButton("W");
    btn.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (!label.isVisible()) {
            label.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
        panel.add(btn);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not use JFrame. I also use maven and WindowBuilder Editor. I am testing in WindowBuilder. I am quite new to WBe.

Comment: Replace the line in your code  "wButton .addActionListener(this);" with wButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (!wlabel.isVisible()) {
     wlabel.setVisible(true);
    }
   }
  });

Comment: `I do not use JFrame.` Then, what ARE you using?  A JLabel must go on a JPanel, and that JPanel must go on a top-level container (such as a JFrame).

Answer (score 0):

Add ActionListener to your button:

```
wButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         //Execute when button is pressed
         wLabel.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Or better practice (I think) is to create separate class that implements ActionListener. But result will be the same. I don't know how big your application is, but I suggest to separate ActionListeners (like separate class I mentioned), just to make your code clear.

Comment: Most likely the problem is not in the button, with this setVisible. Even In the begining when I add the label and write setVisible(false), I still see it. I extend JPanel, so I am not using separate JFrame

Comment: Please post more code, cause with sample app I wrote for testing, it works for me. I guess there must be problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    jLabel1.setVisible(false);
}

private void initComponents(){
     jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });}




   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   {                                         
    jLabel1.setVisible(true);
}
```

This piece of code worked for me, Here `NewJFrame()` is the constructor